# Update path to PHP on OS X El Capitan after updating PHP 5.5.x to 5.6.x

Tags: php, macos

I've updated PHP from 5.5.34 which was installed on my Mac to PHP 5.6.25 using this guide: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx

When I upload a `phpinfo()` script it's showing that I'm using PHP Version 5.6.25 which is what I'm expecting.

However, in Terminal it's seeing the old version of PHP:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.34 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2016 19:16:58)
```

How can I get the Terminal to use the updated version of PHP?

Comment: You should probably just install PHP using homebrew - it's centralized and much easier to manage your packages

Answer (score 1):

As usual nobody answered, but I figured it out so posting the solution...

If you follow that guide you will need to do the following:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

That should get the correct PHP version (7.x if you follow the link right the way through to the end) working in your browser. But your Terminal will still display 5.x

In your home directory create a .bash_profile file:

```
cd ~
nano .bash_profile
```

and put this in it:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Save the file and exit.

Load the .bash_profile:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Now when you do `php -v` you should see it reporting 7.x. So it's using that in your Terminal and browser; all good.

The installer works in a strange way whereby even though you're using PHP 7.x it will put it in a directory called 'php5' (`/usr/local/php5`) but this is a symbolic link to a different directory.